# Javascript weird addition

Tags: javascript

Can anyone answer me why javascript adds up 1.123460 + 0.112210 as 1.2356699999999998
while no way I can come up with that result by manual calculation or by any other compilers..
Am I going crazy or javascript, cannot figure out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/1542290 ?

Answer (score 0):

Its just how JavaScript and many other languages deal with floats. Rounding them to 15 decimal places. Check this  How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)